# Equinox launcher for mac (org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.carbon.macosx) version 3.4.1 doesn't work in 64-bit mac?

Tags: java, macos, 64-bit, osgi, equinox

trying to start bundle org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.carbon.macosx_1.0.101.R34x_v20080731 (part of the eclipse 3.4.1 SDK) on OS X Mavericks with Java jdk 1.7 (64 bit)

getting this error:

```
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=carbon) (osgi.os=macosx) (|(osgi.arch=x86)(osgi.arch=ppc)) )
```

Definitely seems to be complaining about the "x86" part.  The environment:

```
osgi> !SESSION 2014-03-10 11:43:30.320 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=carbon, NL=en_US
```

Does this really not work on 64-bit mac?   Why would such a constraint be put in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse 3.4 is from many years ago (2008). Long before there was a 64-bit Java on Mac. So that native code is 32-bit and thus only works with a 32-bit Java VM. So, you cannot use 3.4 with Java 7 on Mac. You will need to use Java 6 for Mac: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572